# 10's Complement of a negative decimal number

Tags: number-theory

What will be 10's complement of ($-417_{10}$) .

Should it be $10^{3}-(-417)=1417$  ?

No further information in given and I could not find any reference anywhere .

EDIT :

Number of digits are to be assumed equal to 3.

Will the 10's complement of |x| and -|x| be same ?[x is a 3 digit decimal number]

Comment: You computed the subtraction incorrectly.

Comment: I have corrected it. @Hurkyl

Comment: You computed this subtraction wrongly too. (and the left hand side you had before was closer to what you actually wanted)

Comment: This is embarassing . I think this time it's correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many digits you're working in. If you're working with 9 digit numbers, it should be $10^9 - 417$ instead. In arbitrary precision, you would actually have the left-infinite 10-adic numeral

$$ \ldots 99999583$$

Comment: Let's say we are working with 3 digit numbers.

Comment: Also any reference link will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look up two's complement to get the overall idea.

Comment: So, there is no such thing as b's complement of a negative number represented in base b ?

Comment: If you're working with 3 digit numbers, the answer can't be the 4 digit number 1417 you have given in the question.

Comment: we can ignore the carry and then the answer would be 417 .What do you think ?

Comment: No. $10$'s complement is a way to represent positive and negative numbers. The point is that $x$ and $-x$ will have _different_ representations so you can tell which one is which! Take the negative number and add a power of $10$ as already shown in the answer.